# How would you translate "He is somewhat tall?"

Tags: translation

I think my teacher said that to translate "He is somewhat/so-so/not really tall" we would say "他ping高." I was wondering if anyone could help me find the character for "ping" because I am not really sure.

I have tried to look for it but all the definitions I found for "ping" don't really sound like they mean "somewhat/so-so/not really. For example, I have tried 坪, 评,平,凭,瓶,冯,娉 because they all have pinyin "ping" but they don't seem to mean "somewhat/so-so/not really." Can anyone please help? I have tried Google Translate but it has not really worked out. It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**挺** /tǐng/ = **quite**; rather

If a man is 170 cm tall, he is of above-average height for a Chinese male (164.8 cm), and we can describe him as 挺高. But it is not that rare. On the other hand, a Chinese male over 190 cm tall has to be considered 很高

We only describe 姚明 as 很高 (very tall), never 挺高 (quite tall), I mean, he is really tall.

More example:

85% mark is 挺高分數 (quite a high mark - high but not rare); 95% is 很高分數 (a very high mark)

> *How would you translate “He is somewhat tall?”*

他人挺高的 (he is quite tall)

Answer (score 0):

He is tall.
他很高。

He is somewhat tall.
他有点儿高。